# How to find second highest number in Array List without using for loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

How to find second highest number in Array List without using for loop ?

Comment: Sort it, return the `last - 1` number.

Comment: Any efforts of yours ?

Comment: Use a while loop? ;)

Comment: @berry120 That's a valid answer :D

Comment: How is this related to servlets?

Comment: @PakkuDon Once upon a time.. A servlet was an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Similar to the way you find the maximum, only use two variables: maxFoundSoFar and secondMaxFoundSoFar.  Loop through the list.

Answer (score 1):

Sort it first 
then , get the second one in the ArrayList

for Example :

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 arrayList.add(1000);
 arrayList.add(10220);
 arrayList.add(990);
 Collections.sort(arrayList);
 System.out.println(arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 2));
```

Comment: Actually you should `get(arrayList.size() - 2)`.

Comment: This is an unnecessary effort. You can do it in O(n)!

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun: yes you alright :)

Comment: @laune: i'm not good to calculate the big O , but if he use the for loop , then whats the O for it ?/

Comment: @Alya'aGamal One pass over n elements is O(n). Would be for a "for" loop. But the idea isn't to be faster, the idea is to avoid "for".

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account duplicated numbers i.e. what if the 1st and 2nd values are equal (the actual 2nd lowest value might be further down in the array). Easily remedied with some input checking, me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer max2( List<Integer> list ){
  if(list.size() < 2) throw...
  Integer[] max = new Integer[]{ list.get(0), list.get(1) };
  if( max[0] < max[1] ){ max[0] = max[1]; max[1] = list.get(0); }
  return maxdo( list, 2, max );
}

Integer maxdo( List<Integer> list, int pos, Integer[] max ){
  if( pos >= list.size() ) return max[1];
  Integer next = list.get(pos);
  if( next > max[0] ){ max[1] = max[0]; max[0] = next; }
  else if( next > max[1] ){ max[1] = next; }
  return maxdo( list, pos+1, max );
}
```

Not tested, not tried with javac, but I think you'll get the idea.